# Set of $4004$ positive integers so that the sum of any $2003$ of them is not divisible by $2003$

Tags: divisibility, integers

> Is there a set of $4004$ positive integers so that the sum of any
>   $2003$ of them be not divisible by $2003$?

---

No idea how to start with, other than the fact that 2003 is a prime number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What if you have a set of integers where $2002$ of them  $\mod 2003$ give $1$ and $2002$ of them $\mod 2003 $ give $0$.

Then notice you have to choose at least one $1$. But the ones are not enough to give you something divisible by $2003$.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out, I wanted to say mod 2003 zero

Answer (score 2):

By the [Erdos-Ginzburg-Ziv theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16721/egz-theorem-erdos-ginzburg-ziv), given $4005$ integers, the sum of $2003$ of them is a multiple of $2003$ (the same holds with $2n-1$ integers and the sum of $n$ of them being a multiple of $n$, no matter if $n$ is a prime), but that $4005$ is clearly optimal, since we may consider $4004$ integers only, with $2002$ of them being of the form $2003k$ and $2002$ of them being of the form $2003k+1$.